# MySQL: run a script when logging in?

Tags: mysql-5.5

Is it possible, in MySQL, to run a 'login profile' similar to the bash/ksh profile, when connecting with the mysql client? That is to say, something similar to `mysql -e 'select * from a_table'`, but where mysql doesn't terminate after executing the statement?

Answer (score 1):

The mysql client has the `init-command` option, which does what you want, I think.

From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_init-command):

> --init-command=str
>
> SQL statement to execute after connecting to the server. If
>   auto-reconnect is enabled, the statement is executed again after
>   reconnection occurs.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do what I expect, certainly, if I try to start with a 'select something', tehre is no output.

Comment: Then maybe this is your answer? https://serverfault.com/questions/436474/is-it-possible-to-change-the-mysql-welcome-message

Comment: no, I was hoping to display the output of a select, really. It isn't too important, just something that I thought might be useful.

Comment: You can achieve that with cronfy's answer. I don't think there's another way (except adjusting the sources and recompiling).